# Magento 2 Data Migration error

Tags: magento2, database

I'm migrating data from existing Magento store built in CE-1.6.2 to Magento 2 clean installation following Magento official guide here,
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

I have got no errors when I migrate settings, however, once I run the command

```
php bin/magento migrate:data [path to config.xml]
```

I have got a list errors like below,

```
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: adminnotification_inbox
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_datetime
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_int
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_text
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_category_entity_varchar
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cataloginventory_stock
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: search_query
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: checkout_agreement
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: checkout_agreement_store
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_block
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_block_store
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_page
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: cms_page_store
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: store
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: store_group
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: variable
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: variable_value
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon_aggregated
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_eav_attribute_website
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_form_attribute
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_country
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_country_region
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_country_region_name
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: directory_currency_rate
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_label
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_option
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_option_value
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_entity_store
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_element
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_fieldset
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_fieldset_label
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_type
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_form_type_entity
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: importexport_importdata
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: newsletter_subscriber
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_creditmemo
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_creditmemo_comment
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_creditmemo_item
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_comment
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_item
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_address
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_item
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_payment
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status_history
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_address
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_payment
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_shipping_rate
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_comment
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_item
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_track
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_created
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_updated
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status_label
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status_state
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_tax
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_tax_item
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_payment_transaction
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_refunded_aggregated
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_refunded_aggregated_order
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated_order
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: shipping_tablerate
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sitemap
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation_rate
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation_rule
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_class
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_order_aggregated_created
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_order_aggregated_updated
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist
[2016-04-04 10:29:41][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
```

Comment: how do your xmls look? migrate the data to magento2 is a really complex procedure if you have custom tables etc. don't expect it to run out of the box, it's a job for weeks.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: This is not an a error. it is a warning. and this warning is due to something mismatch field in that all database table. Please do migration process once again.